# visibilitychange only execute once when going into fullscreen and exiting from fullscreen

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>

<div id="video">

</div>

<button onclick="enablefullscreen()">Enable</button>
<script>


function enablefullscreen(){
    toggleFullscreen();
}

function toggleFullscreen() {
  let elem = document.getElementById("video");
  elem.requestFullscreen()
}

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', (e) => {
    console.log("visibility change");
}, false);


</script>

</html>
```

i am using this code. The issue is that when user clicks `enable` to go into fullscreen, `visibilitychange` gets called 2 times. When he exits fullscreen, `visibilitychange` gets called 4 times.

Is there any way to only call `visibilitychange` only 1 times when going into fullscreen and exiting from fullscreen?

Comment: When user goes into fullscreen, `visibilitychange` gets called as I said multiple times. There could be many reasons behind this, but my business logic needs to only get called once if one enters into fullscreen or exits from it.

Comment: Okay, so you _want_ to react on visibilitychange for some reason. With your half-finished last sentence, that was not really clear.

Comment: Yes. The final nutshell idea behind this is that I only want to react on visibilitychange when tab changes.  and not when user goes into fullscreen or exits from it. I haven't included this in my main question, but that's the thing I am trying to achieve .

Comment: The example you have shown doesn’t appear to fire the event at all for me in Chrome. And I really don’t see why it should, going from a normal visible state into fullscreen, doesn’t change anything about that it is _still_ visible. But maybe combining it with a check whether you currently _are_ in fullscreen can help fix your issue? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreen

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onfullscreenchange also exists, so maybe you can develop a logic by “connectiong” the info you get from both events somehow.

Comment: It does fire for me. I am on Mac (using chrome). I agree that it shouldn't be firing `visibilitychange` event at all. The solution you said is very tricky because exiting from fullscreen causes `visibilitychange` to get called 4 times which means checking will only work for the first time and what  about other 3? when I check for the first time, I have to somehow make the variable false, and other 3 events come and resuling in my code still being executed

Comment: If you're on windows, I think you're right that it's not firing. but on macos, it does. :(

Comment: If you can properly determine whether the document _is_ in fullscreen mode or not, then it should not matter that much, how often this event fires …?

Comment: depends on users and how often they switch apps or tabs.  If I have the check if(! document.fullScreenElement) { //call my code } , then when user exits from fullscreen, that's where the problem begins as I can't detect that. Even using fullscreenchange doesn't help because visibilitychange gets called 4 times and writing if else statement would only work for the first event.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you need to do when the visibility changes?

Comment: There's 3rd party which I have to call via Api call.